# Understanding the singleton class when aliasing a instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, metaprogramming, definition

I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and the Ruby on Rails v3.2.2 gem. I am trying to learn Metaprogramming "the right way" and at this time I am aliasing an *instance* method in the `included do ... end` block provided by the RoR [`ActiveSupport::Concern`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) module:

```
module MyModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # Builds the instance method name.
    my_method_name = build_method_name.to_sym # => :my_method

    # Defines the :my_method instance method in the including class of MyModule.
    define_singleton_method(my_method_name) do |*args|
      # ...
    end

    # Aliases the :my_method instance method in the including class of MyModule.
    singleton_class = class << self; self end
    singleton_class.send(:alias_method, :my_new_method, my_method_name)        
  end
end
```

"Newbiely" speaking, with a search on the Web I came up with the `singleton_class = class << self; self end` statement and I used that (instead of the `class << self ... end` block) in order to *scope* the `my_method_name` variable, making the aliasing generated dynamically.

I would like to understand exactly *why* and *how* the `singleton_class` works in the above code and if there is a better way (maybe, a more maintainable and performant one) to implement the same (aliasing, defining the singleton method and so on), but "the right way" since I think it isn't so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend Yehuda Katz's [post on metaprogamming on Ruby's self](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/15/metaprogramming-in-ruby-its-all-about-the-self/). Here's my humble summary in response to your question:

In Ruby, all objects have a singleton class (also known as metaclass). Objects inherit first from their singleton class invisibly, then from their explicit class. Ruby classes themselves have their own singleton classes since classes are objects as well. The `class <<` idiom is simply Ruby's syntax for accessing the scope of an object's singleton class.

```
 class Person
   class << self
     # self in this scope is Person's singleton class
   end
 end

 person = Person.new
 person_singleton_class = class << person; self; end
```

Your version of Rails actually provides `singleton_class` as a shortcut. Since `singleton_class` is an available method, you don't need to assign it to a variable in the expression `singleton_class = class << self; self end`:

```
Person.singleton_class 

person = Person.new
person.singleton_class
```

Since a class inherits directly from its singleton class, this is where we want to add class methods dynamically when metaprogramming. Ruby provides a few ways to open up the scope of an object while maintaining access to the surrounding scope: `class_eval` and `instance_eval`. There are subtle differences in the way these behave (Yehuda's post explains this), but you may use either to enter the scope of your singleton class, resolve methods on the singleton class as `self` and still have access to `my_method_name` from the surrounding scope.

All that said, you could make a few small changes to your module:

```
module MyModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # Builds the instance method name.
    my_method_name = build_method_name.to_sym # => :my_method

    # Defines the :my_method instance method in the including class of MyModule.
    define_singleton_method(my_method_name) do |*args|
      # ...
    end

    singleton_class.class_eval do
      # method resolution in scope of singleton class
      alias_method :my_new_method, my_method_name
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with methods that are already existing. What if I want to alias the :delete method that the ActiveRecord Models already have?