# Sending method to child in Ruby class? Inheritance confusion

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
class Bike 
  attr_reader :chain

  def initialize
    @chain = default_chain
  end

  def default_chain
    raise 'SomeError'
  end
end


class MountainBike < Bike
  def initialize
    super
  end

  def default_chain
    4
  end
end

mb = MountainBike.new
p mb.chain
```

When in the initialization we call super, I would expect the default_chain of the super class to be called, and therefore the Exception to be launched. However, it seems that the Bike class actually goes and calls the default_chain method of the original caller. Why is that?

Comment: If you add `puts "self = #{self}"` in `Bike`'s `initialize` method you will get something like this: `#<MountainBike:0x007fc14323f080>#`; that is, `self` is the MountainBike instance.  That is why it first looks in `MountainBike` for `default_chain`, which it finds.

Comment: This is exactly as it should work. Method `MountainBike#initialize` calls `super`, which in turn sends self the message `:default_chain`. Because self is an instance of `MountainBike`, the method lookup starts there, and finds `MountainBike#default_chain` method, which returns `4`. You can see the full lookup sequence by typing `mb.singleton_class.ancestors`.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Your comment would make a fine answer.

Comment: @Alp, I don't want to have too many answers in my profile, my boss would think that all I ever do is chat on SO =)

Answer (score 1):

As said @BorisStitnicky you need to use singleton_class.  For more understanding, in this post you may find info: [Understanding the singleton class when aliasing a instance method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937209/understanding-the-singleton-class-when-aliasing-a-instance-method)

Answer (score 0):

The point of putting a same-named method in a sub-class is to overload that method.
ie to replace it with your new version.

The code will look at the calling sub-class's version of any method - before it starts looking up the ancestry chain for a method, because the sub-class is the *context* of the current code.

So even though the method is referred-to in the superclass... the ruby interpreter will still first look at your sub-class's set of method as the main context.

If you also want to call the parent's one - you must use super in your default_chain method too.
Alternatively rename the one in the parent class to something else and call it from your superclass only.

Answer (score 0):

In object oriented programming, which method is called is solely determined by the receiver and the method name.

- Method name `initialize` is called on the receiver: `MountainBike` instance, for which `MountainBike#initialize` matches, and is executed.
- Within the execution, `super` is called, for which `Bike#initialize` matches, and is executed.
- Within the execution, method name `default_chain` is called on the implicit receiver `self`, which is the `MountainBike` instance. `MountainBike#default_chain` matches, and is executed.

If `Bike#default_chain` were to be called in the last step on the receiver (`MountainBike` instance), it would mean that method calling would depend not only on the receiver and the method name, but also on the context. That would make it too complicated, and would defeat the purpose of object oriented programming. Again, the idea of object oriented programming is that **method call is solely determined by the receiver and the method name, not the context**.