# Associating values from one array to another in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm building a simple program after learning a little bit of Ruby. I'm trying to associate values from one array to another here's what I've got so far.

```
ColorValues = ["Black", "Brown", "Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Cyan", "Blue", "Violet", "Pink", "Grey"]  

(0..127).each_slice(12) {|i| p i}
```

.each_slice returns these arrays

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]

[24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]

[36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47]

[48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]

[60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71]

[72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83]

[84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95]

[96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107]

[108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119]

[120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127]
```

What I'm attempting to do is then take the returned arrays and associate them with each color in the ColorValues[] array

i.e.

```
"Black" =  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
"Brown" = [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
```

I'm sure there's a simple way of doing this I'm just not sure how to go about doing it.

Comment: You cannot assign a value to a string like that.

Answer (score 5):

Using [`Enumerable#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) and [`Hash::[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D)

```
colorValues = ["Black", "Brown", "Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Cyan", "Blue", "Violet", "Pink", "Grey"]  
Hash[colorValues.zip((0..127).each_slice(12))]
# => {"Black"=>[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
#     "Brown"=>[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
#     "Red"=>[24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
#     "Orange"=>[36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47],
#     "Yellow"=>[48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
#     "Green"=>[60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71],
#     "Cyan"=>[72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83],
#     "Blue"=>[84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95],
#     "Violet"=>[96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107],
#     "Pink"=>[108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119],
#     "Grey"=>[120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip for that:

```
ColorValues.zip( (0..127).each_slice(12) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Method `#zip` is convenient, but it turns out that your problem is so frequent in Ruby, that I have overloaded `#>>` operator on `Array` class to perform zipping into a hash. First, install `y_support` gem. Then,

```
require 'y_support/core_ext/array' # or require 'y_support/all'
h = ColorValues >> ( 0..127 ).each_slice( 12 ) # returns a hash like in falsetru's answer
h["Black"] #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Comment: Nice answer. +1 for introducing to a new gem. Long time no see. You answered, [be aware from your Boss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669022/sending-method-to-child-in-ruby-class-inheritance-confusion#comment32754613_21669022) :-)